# I cannot get rid of &gt; and &lt; using javascript

Tags: javascript, escaping

I looked up some SO questions but I could not find exactly what i wanted. So, here is the code and the problem.

```
var cell=document.createElement('td');
cell.appendChild( document.createTextNode(unescape('Test <br>')));
alert("Content: " + cell.innerHTML);
```

I want the `alert` appear as `Test <br>` but instead it appears as `Test &lt;br&gt;`. I tried many things like trying to unescape after the node is created, tried to unescape while creating the node(above), tried alerting the `innerHTML` unescaped but none seem to have worked. Whatever I tried, I failed to render the output as I desired and now I need your help.

Comment: Is this inline-javascript or is the script stored in a separate file?

Comment: @Niko It's seperate file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing is create a textNode < br > and its converting the < and > to html code. You have to insert an element if you want the alert to properly show < br > tag. Hope this helps you

http://jsfiddle.net/7b5Yk/

```
var cell=document.createElement('td');
var br = document.createElement('br');
cell.appendChild( document.createTextNode(unescape('Test')));
cell.appendChild(br)
alert("Content: " + cell.innerHTML);
```

Comment: No problems :) this is a forum and we are all here to help eachother out

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you absolutely need to do `innerHTML` for some reason but if you change it to `innerText` you should get the desired result.

```
alert("Content: " + cell.innerText);
```

Seems it all depends on if you are actually intending to add text or if you want that

 to be an actual line break or not.  If you want it to act as a line break in
the td you should most likely go with Ziinloader's approach.

Comment: No without the innerHTML the code would return object HTMLtableCellElement and no the desired textNode

Comment: True that @Ziinloader. You need the innerHTML to display the _inside_ of the '<td>' element.

Comment: Edited my comment to reflect the difference in needs, answer depends on if the `<br>` was supposed to be treated as a HTML element or as simple text. http://jsfiddle.net/F682p/